# Is it possible to screen scrape and display only one div/ Table

Tags: c#

Is it possible to webscrape using HTTPWebRequest or webclient and display only a specfic div or table like the example below?

This is one div from a page of other divs, just to give you a structure example.

```
     <div id="DIV5">

            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>

                <tr class="">

                <tr class="last">

            </table>

</div>
```

I have this simple code which displays the HTML from the page, but I am looking for a way to display only one DIV or One table.

```
namespace SimpleScreenScrape
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string html = this.GetWebsiteHtml(this.textBox1.Text);
            this.richTextBox1.Text = html;
        }

        private string GetWebsiteHtml(string url)
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Dispose();
            reader.Dispose();
            return result;
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ , using which you can select the nodes that you want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, once you have the HTML document (stored in your `result` variable), you can parse it and display only the parts of it that you want.

I suggest you use a dedicated HTML parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - this will allow you to easily extract only the HTML you are interested in.

Comment: This is the way to go! Don't try to parse your HTML with a regex! You'll just end up crafting something unholy and unmaintainable that will fail when dealing with malformed HTML.

Comment: @calebd see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for exactly why you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML ;)

Comment: Cheers, just used HTML Agility, what a great tool. Now I have the problem of converting this back into a table?Sep07:0007:00DEPARTEDUS5339NZ303Christchurch01 Sep07:0007:00DEPARTEDNZ101&nbsp;Sydney01 Sep07:0007:00DEPARTEDAC6105NZ101Sydney01 Sep07:0007:00&nbsp;CA5111NZ101Sydney01 Sep07:0007:00&nbsp;CO6771NZ101Sydney01 Sep07:0007:00DEPARTEDDJ8001NZ101Sydney01

Comment: @Rhys - Comments are not a good place for code samples. I suggest asking a new question...